# Rails Haml element styling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, styles, haml

I have a custom style in my css for a background image I want to apply:

```
.specialbg {

 background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XMuKF.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;

 }
```

I want to apply this style to my body element in HAML, but I'm not sure how the arguments are setup. I'm thinking that the following should work:

```
%html
 %head
  %body
   .specialbg
```

But it doesn't. I've read the haml styling reference manual, but can't see where I'm wrong -- I've just adopted haml, and I'd appreciate any help or pointers!

**Stack Q's I've referenced:**

[scaml "illegal nesting" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918684/scaml-illegal-nesting-error)

[Background images do not render on Ruby on Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623251/background-images-do-not-render-on-ruby-on-rails-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the class to your body element, you would just append the class to the tag like this:

```
%html
  %head
  %body.specialbg
```

It could be a typo in your example, but the way your example is set up, you are putting your body tag *within* the head tag

If you put the `.specialbg` class on its own line, it will create a div inside of your body tag with `class='specialbg'`

Comment: Wowzers, thanks Dan! I really appreciate your clarifying the syntax for me. I learn something new everyday, neat.